# How to place a function inside a Class?

Tags: jquery, class, constructor, ion-range-slider

I am using ion.RangeSliders and I need to initialize about 10 sliders. So I decided to use JavaScript Class constructor method.

This is what I've done:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $("#example").DataTable();

  class IonRangeWrapper {
    constructor(range, min, max, inputFrom, inputTo) {
      range.ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        min: min,
        max: max,
        from: min,
        to: max,
        onStart: updateInputs,
        onFinish: updateInputs
      });
      var instance = range.data("ionRangeSlider");

      inputFrom.on("input", function () {
        var val = $(this).prop("value");
        if (val < min) { val = min; }
        else if (val > to) { val = to; }
        instance.update({ from: val });
      });

      inputTo.on("input", function () {
        var val = $(this).prop("value");
        if (val < from) { val = from; }
        else if (val > max) { val = max; }
        instance.update({ to: val });
      });
    }
  }

  function updateInputs(data) {
    from = data.from;
    to = data.to;
    inputFromAge.prop("value", from);
    inputToAge.prop("value", to);
    table.draw();
  }
  
  // Age Slider
  var rangeAge = $(".rangeAge");
  var inputFromAge = $(".inputFromAge");
  var inputToAge = $(".inputToAge");
  var minAge = 10;
  var maxAge = 70;

  new IonRangeWrapper(rangeAge, minAge, maxAge, inputFromAge, inputToAge);
  
  // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
  $("#minAge, #maxAge").keyup(function () {
    table.draw();
  });
});

/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
  var minAge = parseInt($("#minAge").val(), 10);
  var maxAge = parseInt($("#maxAge").val(), 10);
  var age = parseFloat(data[3]) || 0; // use data for the age column

  if (
    (isNaN(minAge) && isNaN(maxAge)) ||
    (isNaN(minAge) && age <= maxAge) ||
    (minAge <= age && isNaN(maxAge)) ||
    (minAge <= age && age <= maxAge)
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <h4 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom:0;">Age Filter</h4>
  <div style="display: flex; margin: 10px;">
    <div>
      <input type="text" size="4" class="inputFromAge" id="minAge" name="minAge" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; padding: 0 10px;">
      <input type="text" class="rangeAge" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" size="4" class="inputToAge" id="maxAge" name="maxAge" value="0" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sydney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/10/09</td>
        <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>2010/12/22</td>
        <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2010/11/14</td>
        <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2011/06/07</td>
        <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fiona Green</td>
        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>2010/03/11</td>
        <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shou Itou</td>
        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>2011/08/14</td>
        <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michelle House</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Sydney</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2011/06/02</td>
        <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Suki Burks</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>2009/10/22</td>
        <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/05/07</td>
        <td>$145,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
        <td>Team Leader</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2008/10/26</td>
        <td>$235,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Martena Mccray</td>
        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/03/09</td>
        <td>$324,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Unity Butler</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/12/09</td>
        <td>$85,675</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/12/16</td>
        <td>$164,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
        <td>Secretary</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2010/02/12</td>
        <td>$109,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shad Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/11/13</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

As you see I made one Class constructor and it was the best I could do. My question is: how to place `function updateInputs` inside `class IonRangeWrapper`? To clarify, I would like to do something like this below:

```
class IonRangeWrapper {
  constructor() {
    // init ion.rangeSlider
    // create instance
    // connect it to inputs
  }
  
  update() {} // public method: function updateInputs()
}

// create as many instances of that class as needed:
const slider1 = new IonRangeWrapper(config);
const slider2 = new IonRangeWrapper(config);
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/arnonrdp/pen/XWpgwjE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var table = $("#example").DataTable();
class IonRangeWrapper {
    inputFrom = null;
    inputTo = null;
    table = null;
    slider_range = { from: 0, to: 0 };
    constructor(range, min, max, inputFrom, inputTo, table) {
        var _this = this;
        this.inputFrom = inputFrom;
        this.inputTo = inputTo;
        this.table = table;

        range.ionRangeSlider({
            type: "double",
            min: min,
            max: max,
            from: min,
            to: max,
            onStart: (data) => _this.update(data),
            onFinish: (data) => _this.update(data)
        });
        var instance = range.data("ionRangeSlider");

        inputFrom.on("input", function () {
            var { to } = _this.slider_range;
            var val = $(this).prop("value");
            if (val < min) { val = min; }
            else if (val > to) { val = to; }
            instance.update({ from: val });
        });

        inputTo.on("input", function () {
            var { from } = _this.slider_range;
            var val = $(this).prop("value");
            if (val < from) { val = from; }
            else if (val > max) { val = max; }
            instance.update({ to: val });
        });
    }
    update(data) {
        var from = data.from;
        var to = data.to;
        this.slider_range = { from, to };
        this.inputFrom.prop("value", from);
        this.inputTo.prop("value", to);
        this.table.draw();
    }
}

// Age Slider
var rangeAge = $(".rangeAge");
var inputFromAge = $(".inputFromAge");
var inputToAge = $(".inputToAge");
var minAge = 10;
var maxAge = 70;

new IonRangeWrapper(rangeAge, minAge, maxAge, inputFromAge, inputToAge, table);
```

Comment: This way, table and slider filters works, but the inputs does not update the slider. I made another CodePen with your code to compare both: [CodePen 1](https://codepen.io/arnonrdp/pen/XWpgwjE) - [CodePen 2](https://codepen.io/arnonrdp/pen/rNjzaee)

Comment: I also tried to ignore `update(data)` and used directly on `onStart: function(data) { }` and like [Range Slider documentation](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/showcase.html) shows on second slider but it didn't work.

Comment: Your code returns me `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: to`. I tried to declare it, but no success.

Comment: I have updated provided code in answer. Please try the same and check once

Comment: You are a natural! Thank you so much!